# finding minimum number of ratings needed in recommendation systems?

Tags: mahout, recommendation-engine

Is there an intelligent way to find out the minimum number of ratings you need from a user to start recommending items (Accurately).

Like, say.. rate "x" items before I start recommending anything to you. How do you find out that "x" based on a dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea is to hold out all data from N users that each have at least some moderate number M of ratings. Then add 1 rating from each user, and make recommendations for each one. Assess the quality of the recommendations; you can do it by hand, or evaluate some metric like mean average precision / nDCG / AUC.

Then add another rating from each user and repeat. You should find that quality is improving over time, but less with each rating. You then just pick your tradeoff -- when do you judge that waiting for another rating is worth the expected increase in quality?

There's no one right answer. But I would be surprised if your use case and algorithm were such that the answer is more than about 4.

Answer (score 1):

There has been work done in understanding how many items should actually be in a users profile to get a 'satisfactory' recommendation performance. It has been found that generally 10 is a good number

http://wanlab.poly.edu/recsys12/recsys/p27.pdf

You can check the paper out to answer any specific question you will have, but at a high level. It's 8 - 20 (10 being preferred) items in a user profile to recommend movie esque recommendations. They performed the typical offline (simulation) and online (user based) study to determine that number.